# R, dpylr handling variablenames that are identical to column names

Tags: r, dplyr

When using dplyr and variablenames which are identical to column names, how do I distinguish between the two?

```
test <- c(1,2)
df <- data.frame(test = c(3,4))
df %>% mutate(test = test) # does not change anything
```

I also tried something like

```
test <- c(1,2)
df <- data.frame(test = c(3,4))
df %>% mutate(test = interp(~x, x = as.name("test")))
```

To force the use of the (global) variable "test" instead, unfortunately no success.

How do I handle such situations?

Edit: 
When having non non-global vars, i.e. function arguments

```
foo <- function(test) {
  df <- data.frame(test = c(3,4))
  env <- environment()
  df %>% mutate(test = env[["test"]])
}
foo(1:2)
```

Does the trick

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(test = .GlobalEnv$test)`

Comment: If you are creating the function with arguments, calling `foo()` is not making sense.  You can call `foo(1:2)` or `foo(6:7)#
  test
1    6
2    7`

Comment: Ah, stupid me, thx!

Comment: related: in dplyr 0.6 (or the current development version) to specifically refer to the column in the data.frame you can use `df %>% mutate(new = .data$test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.GlobalEnv` to extract the objects

```
df %>% 
    mutate(test = .GlobalEnv[["test"]])
#    test
#1    1
#2    2
```

Comment: Thx, but what about non global envs?

foo <- function() {
  test <- c(1,2)
  df <- data.frame(test = c(3,4))
  env <- environment()
  df %>% mutate(test = env[["test"]])
}
foo()

Does work, but seems ugly. Is there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: @FabianGehring  If you create a env with `env1 <- new.env()`, you willl not have any surprises

Comment: Can you give an example? The "workaround" also does not work, when the variable "test" is not defined within the funcion, but passed as an argument. See updated original post

Comment: @FabianGehring  Your function is working for me in the current state

Comment: The one updated in the orignial post (using function argument) does not for me.

Comment: @FabianGehring  I just commented below your post